# Notation - Odd and Even Cases in one

Tags: notation

Consider the function 
$$\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{2\mu}f(r)(-1)^r\qquad \text{for even $\mu$}\\
\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{2\mu}f(r)(-1)^{r+1}\qquad \text{for odd $\mu$}\\\end{cases}$$

> Is there a neat notation where the two expressions can be combined into one which will automatically cater for both even and odd values of $\mu$ without splitting into two cases?

Comment: $$(-1)^\mu\sum _{r=0}^{2\mu} f(r)(-1)^r$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - Thanks. That works perfectly. Would you like to post this as an answer?  I was thinking of using the indicator function but that's probably too cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{r=0}^{2\mu}f(r)(-1)^{r+\mu}$$

Comment: Thanks. That works very well. As mentioned in the comment above, I was thinking of using the indicator function but that's probably too cumbersome.